# Refresh DataGridView in Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms let it be Form A and Form B. When I click save button on Form B I want the DataGridView of Form A to refresh.

Which method should I use?

Comment: There isn't any single method you could call to achieve this, but the idea is to trigger an event which will perform the necessary action in the Form A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a event is one way of doing this. Below is another way which is more object oriented.

Add public Refresh method in FormA.

```
public void RefreshDataGrid()     
{       
   //Do refresh    
}
```

Pass the instance of FormA to FormB when constructing FormB. You have to create FormB contructor to take FormA instance.

```
    private FormA myFormA;        
    public FormB(FormA formA)        
    {        
        myFormA = formA;        
    }
```

Now you can call FormA.ResfreshGrid() method from FormB.

```
myFormA.RefreshGrid();
```

Answer (score 1):

implement code in Form A like this:

```
private delegate void DEmpty();
public void RefreshDataGrid()
{
   this.Invoke(new DEmpty(datagrid.Refresh));
}
```

then call this when button is clicked on B

Comment: I misspelled DEmpty in invoke, now its fixed

Comment: REfreshDataGrid is not appear in B .Why ?

Comment: Because you have to get reference to A, and then call the function RefreshDataGrid
Like this `A _aref;
_aref.RefreshDataGrid();` 
Change the constructor of B so that one of its params is var of type A, then inside the ctor assign the value to a local var

Answer (score 0):

Create a method for binding the gridview, call this method on form load of form A, and if the form is already opened, you have to use its instance (of form A), and call the same binding method of Form A for gridview binding.