# refresh data grid view after updating in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

i have a data grid view and details for a particular table.i update the details, But it doesn't get updated in the data grid view?my update statement works properly because, once i exit the project, it gets updated.

```
cmd.CommandText = "update emp_tbl set sal= '" & SalTextBox.Text & "' where id='" & id & "'"
```

table name: `emp_tbl`

datagridview: `emp_tbldatagridview`

update button :

```
cn.Open()

cmd.CommandText = "update emp_tbl set sal= '" & SalTextBox.Text & "' where id='" & id & "'"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Comment: windows forms in visual studio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374348/refresh-button-refreshing-data-grid-view-after-inserting-deleting-updating

this question is similar but its answers dint help ?

Comment: realized that, dgv is forms only.

Comment: Are you refreshing your data grid after the command is executed?

Comment: Yes, But the refresh button's coding is fill()-default Query

Comment: Are you in winforms or asp.net ?  Yes, it matters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to re-bind it:

```
     BindingSource binding = new BindingSource(); //req. by win forms
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     dt.Load(sql_command.ExecuteReader());
     dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

This is the best way I've found to do it in win forms, .update doesn't work because it needs to actually re-pull the data from SQL.

Comment: Where do i write this coding?

If i write it in a button named refresh, will it work?

Comment: Yep, wherever you want to refresh the dgv. Adjust your object names appropriately.  I use it on my submit button to reload the page with updated values.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!

  Will check and let you know!

Comment: Do i need to import anything?

Comment: If you are free, Could you pls explain to me just roughly what this code means? i replaced the code with this, where emp_tblbindingsource is my binding source!

   ` Emp_tblBindingSource  = new BindingSource(); //req. by win forms`  but*;* is it right? to use ; ?

Comment: If you could pass your mail id, i could mail to you my print screens!!

  Because coding is big

Comment: or mine is vbstudent2013@gmail.com

Comment: its ok!

i am sorry,

i am doing a project so i needed to view this way with datagridview updated...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just try to reuse your startup code in datagridview or recall the startup code from the data.
It was the simple way at all.
Cause your startup code is for binding your database to your datagridview.
So, everytime you save, your code just save it and not work for rebind it again. So, what you need just try to rebind by recall the startup code

Comment: the datagridview shows the updated value only after i end my project!

Comment: From reopen the project? is like that... then that is what i told about.. just try to recall your first startup code.. cause that is reload code..

Comment: Because when i END my project and again run it, The values in my data grid view are already updated!

Comment: first startup code means? my first form that shows when i run my project?

Comment: Just like random said, that is what i mean.

Comment: what code did you use when you run your project? of course the code your use to run your project is calling your database to your project, isnt it? Then that is what i said your startup code, just reuse it again for the button to update.