# How to refresh datagrid from an sql query

Tags: sql, wpf, datagrid

I had an a function that populate a datagrid.

```
Public Sub GridMiner()
    'check summary and database
    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "Select roomnumber AS [Room], [end] AS [Check out at], hours as [on] FROM rooms where [end] between ? and ?"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Now.AddDays(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Now.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds)
        gridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        da = Nothing
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

It populates my datagrid named gridSummary

now when I save some data to my database table from different form, my datagrid won't refresh its value and I had decided to create a refresh button.

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
    GridMiner()
End Sub
```

instead of refreshing the data on my datagrid, it adds the same content and its new data.

Comment: Have you tried calling DataBind on the data grid?

Comment: Have you not tried `this.YourDataGrid.Refresh();`?

Comment: gridSummary.DataSource = null gridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

Comment: @LordTakkera how to do that? My function is for an online sql that's why I am not using databind, correct me if I am wrong but databind is used on the datagrid right? and I am not really know-how on how to use databind.

Comment: @MarkLaREZZA did that but nothing happens.

Comment: Databind is used on the datagrid, and basically says "UI, get the data from data source and display it, it might have changed". Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7c2tz18(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Blam `gridSummary.DataSource = null` is this code right? it seems their some error on null as its not a register value/property. And I `gridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` in my function

Comment: @LordTakkera - well, I am using sql that's why I don't used databind. And I don't want the datagrid to be editable.

Comment: I'm not sure why either of those things affect the use of the DataBind function. SQL is just a data source, it shouldn't affect how you get that data to the UI. Also, DataBind() wouldn't affect the editability of the grid (that has to do with IsEnabled/IsEditable properties).

Comment: Ok. Can you help me reassigned that databind to my current code? or a way around just to refresh it? Since the code is already working and I just needed to refresh it.

Comment: I think all you need to do is call gridSummary.DataBind() after you set the data source. I have had to do some weird stuff with setting the DataSource to null first which you may want to try if it doesn't work right away.

Comment: Thanks for the ligh @LordTakkera, I already make some edits and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a primary key in order to merge the tables correctly.

> *"If primary key information is present, any duplicate rows are reconciled and only appear once in the DataTable that corresponds to the DataSet. Primary key information may be set either through FillSchema, by specifying the PrimaryKey property of the DataTable, or by setting the MissingSchemaAction property to AddWithKey."* - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fillschema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So by calling `FillSchema` *before* `da.Fill(ds)` will ensure that the dataset has the corect schema.

```
da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source)
```

Comment: Hello i am not merging any datable

Comment: If you're calling fill more than once on the same `ds` and `dt` it's indeed merging my friend.

Comment: I stand corrected. However I don't wnat them to be merge, I only need them to refresh. I have created my answer of my refresh button above. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @LordTakker and to all who commented

I found the answer through new dataset and it did the trick. See code:

```
Private Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click


        Try
            con.Open()
            sql = "Select roomnumber AS [Room], [end] AS [Check out at], hours as [on] FROM rooms where [end] between ? and ?"
            cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Now.AddDays(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Now.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(ds)
            gridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


            datatb = New DataTable()
            datatb.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            gridSummary.DataSource = datatb

            da = Nothing
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Now this working. Can anyone tell me if this is the best practice.

According to `Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå` 
With this solution you're stuck with two instances of your table. datatb and ds.Tables(0). Also, you're loading the table twice, da.Fill(ds) and datatb.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader()). And, by changing the datasource of your grid you lose all the selection made by the user.

So I have edited the code above to:

```
Public Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        con.Open()
        sql = "Select roomnumber AS [Room], [end] AS [Check out at], hours as [on] FROM rooms where [end] between ? and ?"
        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Now.AddDays(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Now.AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
        datatb = New DataTable()
        datatb.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        gridSummary.DataSource = datatb

        da = Nothing
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Binding source like in [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Ops sorry about this, I dim a new dataset insteads and it did the trick. I was reading here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231036/refresh-data-grid-view-after-updating-in-vb-net)

Comment: With this solution you're stuck with two instances of your table. `datatb` and `ds.Tables(0)`. Also, you're loading the table twice, `da.Fill(ds)` and `datatb.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())`. _And_, by changing the datasource of your grid you lose all the selection made by the user.

Comment: If your table has a primary key, see my solution. If not, clear the table before filling, and accept the changes afterwords.

Comment: Okey I have applied `da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source)` to my code replacing  and got this error. `OledbCommand.Prepare method requires all parameters to have an explicitly set of type.` Note: I added this on my `GridMiner()` before `da.fills(ds)`. Which doesn't work. Also, I removed `da.Fill(ds)` and `          gridSummary.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` in my button refresh (which is my current solution)

Comment: Firstly, when using `AddWithValue` the data type of the value should correspond to the sql column data type. Your passing a string/varchar in your parameters `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. Change to `Date.Parse(Now.AddDays(0).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))` Secondly, do not remove `da.Fill(ds)` as this will fill the data. Notice that `da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source)` will only fill the schema: Table name, column names, constraints, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know the proper implementation of this however my codes works now as for what I have it intended. Don't worry I appreciate your help and I will try to understand this one and create another solution with your comments as my notes. Thank you so much.