# Show data from Database in Datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a problem showing data from database in my DataGridView (dataGridView1). I have a button (btnInsert) which saves input data to database, but to show the data in the datagridview I have to restart the application. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your save button, rebind again the startup code.

```
 BindingSource binding = new BindingSource(); //req. by win forms
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Load(sql_command.ExecuteReader());
```

this.ticket_1 TableAdapter.Fill(this.ticketDataSet2.Ticket_1);
     dgv.DataSource = dt;

This is the best way I've found to do it in win forms, .update doesn't work because it needs to actually re-pull the data from SQL.
or you can try to check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374348/refresh-button-refreshing-data-grid-view-after-inserting-deleting-updating)

Comment: what i need to write here " dt.Load(""sql_command "".ExecuteReader());:S i am new in C#   @Arwin Zhang

Comment: you just need to change the SQL_Command to your OleDBCommand (VB.NET), how about you post your All code, then i will know and can said more detail. Cause i was using converter from C# to VB.NET to help you. What i know only vb.net :) @user2160781

Comment: thenks a lot from you.. i restored it ..in button insert i append this code  
this.ticket_1 TableAdapter.Fill(this.ticketDataSet2.Ticket_1); and works :)

Comment: yes, it just rebind it again actually. Mark it as answer if it is your answer

Answer (score 0):

After your event handler is fired, you need to set your datagrid's datasource property with a datatable that contains data from a query. Once this is done, bind your datagrid like so:

```
dataGrid1.DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
```