# Different datasource for cells in one datagrid comboboxcolumn

Tags: winforms, datagridview, combobox, datasource, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have two combobox columns in datagridview, and trying to set datasource for the second one based on what's selected in the first one.

Unfortunately, not having much luck with it. I'm trying to process two events: CellBeginEdit and PopupClosing, even though I think the first event is enough.

What's weird about this problem is that instead of getting the comboboxcolumn cells to show the proper member collections, I get them to display the datasource of the last comboboxcolumn that I opened in this datagridview, even thought during debugging I can see that datasource property of the combobox cell is set up to what I want.

Here is my code:

```
switch ((JobType)(Enum.Parse(typeof(JobType), dgvScheduledJobs.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgvColumnJobType.Index].Value.ToString())))
{
    case JobType.Upload:
        {
            (this.dgvScheduledJobs[this.dgvColumnSource.Index, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = _datasources;
            break;
        }
    case JobType.Extract:
        {
            (this.dgvScheduledJobs[this.dgvColumnSource.Index, e.RowIndex] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).DataSource = _queries;
            break;
        }
    default:
        {
            break;
        }
}
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Sorry guys. The problem was due to us using class derived from DataGridViewoComboBoxColumn, where we override the control used in DataGridViewComboBoxCell. So it's a problem created by us.

Generally I think the above approach should work though.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a refresh issue with the DataGrid. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374348/refresh-button-refreshing-data-grid-view-after-inserting-deleting-updating) post.