# Value from data source in not been displayed in gridview after binding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, dataset

Following code sets the `AutoGenerateColumns` to true in `form_load` event:

```
gvTables.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Following is the code to bind `gridview` `gvTables`:

```
Query ="select name from sys.tables";  
DataSet tablesDataSet = new DataSet("TableData");
OleDbDataAdapter tablesDataAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, this.Connection);
tablesDataAdaptor.Fill(tablesDataSet);
gvTables.DataSource = tablesDataSet;
```

The Code runs fine. Even data is been retrieved into `dataset` `tableDataSet`, but the value is not been displayed into `gridview` control.

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: @EhsanUllah No I am working with Windows forms

Comment: @Priscy set autogeneratecolumns =true and see the result

Comment: @EhsanUllah My edited post clearly states that,i am still getting the problem, after setting autogeneratecolumns =true

Comment: This sounds like a refresh issue with the DataGrid. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374348/refresh-button-refreshing-data-grid-view-after-inserting-deleting-updating) post.
This is a *very* common issue.

Comment: Did you bind the gridview using
gvTables.DataBind();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Got the solution for this question. The solution is been posted in an orderly manner below:**

1) Declaration of a new variable in the `class` is as given below:

```
private DataSet _Records = null;
```

2) Set the `property` of the new variable:

```
public DataSet Records
{ get { return this._Records; } set { this._Records = value; } }
```

2) Following is the code in the click event:

```
Query ="select name from sys.tables";  

GetDataSetForQuery(Query);//Set the data set using GetDataSetForQuery(Query) method
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.Datasource = this.Records.Tables[0] ;
gvTables.Datasource = bs;
```

4) Following is the code for `GetDataSetForQuery(string sqlQuery)` method:

```
    private bool GetDataSetForQuery(string sqlQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, this.Connection);
            da.Fill(ds);
            this.Records = ds;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        finally { }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Call the following function after your code.

```
gvTables.SetDataBinding(tablesDataSet , "Data");
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This **is** an answer. I'm simply redirecting him to its source.

Comment: Post it as a comment then

Comment: Changed to an answer. Added previous statement as comment.