# How to refresh datagridview after pressing a button

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Hello I am making a small winforms app for a school with a local SQL database.I am using DataGridView to display the Data,but after I add a new student the DataGridView doesn't refresh.

```
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open");
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Students(Grade,Class,Name,sName) VALUES (@Grade,@Class,@Name,@sName)", con);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grade", cbGrade.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", comboClass.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbFName.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", tbSName.Text);

try
        {
            int exec = cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if(exec>0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Added");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not added");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong");
            con.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Please check these two links

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374348/refresh-button-refreshing-data-grid-view-after-inserting-deleting-updating

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting

Answer (score 0):

Everything works.

```
            string query = "select * from students";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            DGVStudents.DataSource = dt;
```