# How to delete one to mutlply rows at one time by selecting check box in datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview

I am having trouble with deleting one to multiply rows in `DataGridView` by selecting check box and clicking the delete button. When i click the delete button nothing happens and neither appears if there is an error.

Here is my code

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;


private void btnDeleteCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in gridCustomer.Rows)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(item.Cells[6].Value.ToString()))
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "delete from Customer where customerID = '" + item.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use debug and see why nothing happens. Also don't use global connection, command and reader.

Comment: put a try catch and see if the app has an error !! i think the problem is with your item.cells[6], try to put nsame instead of index

Comment: When you check the CheckBox, do you validate is it checked or not like `CheckBox.Checked == true`? Get the CheckBox index and try doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can see you didn't check whether the `CheckBox` is checked or not as follows:

```
if(Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value) == true)
```

Get the index or position of the `CheckBox` that are being checked and finally their ids to delete.

For more, see this link - [Delete Rows With CheckBox in DataGridView](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Delete-multiple-rows-from-DataGridView-based-on-CheckBox-selection-in-Windows-Forms-Application-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: Hi it works but i having having a problem with the datagridview  as its not refreshing after the row has been deleted

Comment: cn.Open();
                    cmd.CommandText = "delete from Customer where customerID = '" + item.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    gridCustomer.Update();
                    cleartxt();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Deleted");


                    cn.Close();

Comment: I have have put that it in and is still not refreshing

Comment: No it is not refreshing the datagridview

Comment: Try this - `gridCustomer.Refresh();  gridCustomer.Update();`

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374348/refresh-button-refreshing-data-grid-view-after-inserting-deleting-updating

Comment: Did you write any method to show the data in `DataGridView`? If so, share it or put it inside the button click event at the end like `ShowData();`.

Comment: Yeah i did that

Comment: loadgridCustomer();

Comment: Make sure to put the method at the end of the button click event.

Comment: Error display The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

Comment: Make sure to close the `Con.Open()` and `Con.Close()` or for the reader, do the same.