# Refresh Datagridview from another Form not working

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, refresh, auto-update

I have 2 forms , in first form i have one datagridview and i bind data to it , now in form 2 i update data and i want to refresh datagridview in form 1 
i use this method:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.RefreshGrid();
```

I'm so confused !
when i debug code, it's ok and RefreshGrid() function will run.
but nothing happen in datagridview.
this is my function for refresh datagridview:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext m = new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var q = from p in m.TblAghsats
                    select p;

            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (TblAghsat f in q)
            {
                string[] row1 = new string[] { f.Name , f.Family };
                if (row1 != null)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
            }
        }
```

please somebody help me !

Comment: This is a common error. You are creating a new instance of form1. The call goes to this instance (not visible) and does nothing. You need to call the RefreshGrid from the correct instance.

Comment: To solve the problem Steve points out, have your instance of Form2 (as I guess it is called) hold a reference to your original instance of Form1.  You can pass that instance in when you create Form2 by adding a property to Form2, something like `public Form1 TheOtherForm { get; set; }`

Comment: would you please explain more? what i have to do now? i always have problem for refreshing datagridview in Winforms

Comment: To echo @Steve's comment: the `new` keyword is `new` for a reason.  You are creating a *new* Form1 and then refreshing its grid rather than refreshing the grid on the "old" (already-created) Form1.

Comment: "what i have to do now?": learn about object references, and learn the difference between a class and an object (object = instance of the class).

Comment: To understand what we are talking about try to add a frm.Show(); before the call to RefreshGrid.

Comment: Imagine there is a telephone object in your pocket that is ringing.  You want to answer it.  You try `Phone phone = new Phone(); phone.Answer();` but nothing happens.  Why?  Because you created a new phone object that had nothing to do with the ringing phone, and then you answered the new one, leaving the ringing phone untouched.

Comment: @Steve That is a very good idea.

Comment: @Steve nothing happens!

Comment: @phoog so i have to access the old form1, would you please guide me to good reference about "learn about object references, and learn the difference between a class and an object" ?

Comment: [This question is like yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621615/refresh-datagridview-in-windows-form?rq=1). Study its answer

Comment: You could read any book about object-oriented programming.  (I'd pick one on C# if I were you!).  If you're cheap like me, you can read MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/liBRary/67ef8sbd(v=vs.110).aspx.  It might take you a while to find what you need here, though.

Comment: @phoog that seems good! i will do that , thank